# How do I access the property of one of the entities in a list in a Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How do I access the property of one of the instances in a list, outside a loop?

```
<table>
    {% for field in fields %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ field.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ field.value }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    The value of the last field is: {{ WHAT_GOES_HERE??? }}
</table>
```

What should WHAT_GOES_HERE be? I've tried fields|last.value, fields.-1.value, etc, but don't know the correct syntax. I'd like to use that value to dynamically create a link (with a parameter pointing to the start of the next set of values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django provides the [forloop object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for) for just this case:

```
<table>
    {% for field in fields %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ field.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ field.value }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% if forloop.last %}
            The value of the last field is: {{ field.value }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```